# How to order two columns simultaneously

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I would like the "YEAR" column to be arranged in the order "1970,1971,1972,1973", while the "AMOUNT" column should be in ascending order simultaneously. Also, i would like additional rows to be created to complete the number of years in column "YEAR".

```
K <- data.frame("YEAR" = c(1970,1972,1973,1971,1972,1971,1973,1970,1970),
"AMOUNT" = c(100,100,200,100,400,300,700,200,800),
"DISTANCE" = c(12,3,9,12,25,26,10,7,15))
```

This is my desired result:

```
K <- data.frame("YEAR" = c(1970,1971,1972,1973,1970,1971,1972,1973,1970,1971,1972,1973),
                "AMOUNT" = c(100,100,100,200,200,300,400,700,800,"NA","NA","NA"),
                "DISTANCE" = c(12,3,12,9,7,26,25,10,15,"NA","NA","NA"))
```

Comment: Question is not clear. How do you know which 1970 belongs to which group of 4 years?

Comment: I understand your question regarding the ordering, but I do not understand why you want DISTANCE 3 suddenly belong to year 1972 instead of the year 1971. You just want to sort all columns as it were independently?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're planning to generalise this solution, so this might not be ideal but it gets to what you want.

```
data.frame( YEAR = rep(sort(unique(K$YEAR)),3),
            AMOUNT = sort(K$AMOUNT)[1:12],
            DISTANCE = K$DISTANCE[1:12])

   YEAR AMOUNT DISTANCE
1  1970    100       12
2  1971    100        3
3  1972    100        9
4  1973    200       12
5  1970    200       25
6  1971    300       26
7  1972    400       10
8  1973    700        7
9  1970    800       15
10 1971     NA       NA
11 1972     NA       NA
12 1973     NA       NA
```

Comment: No need to sort the last column

Comment: Good spot.  Thanks.